# How to utilize join to make a simple report

Tags: mysql, sql, join

I have a simple table named 'PizzaData' which contains the following columns:

1. `cust_id INTEGER NOT NULL`
2. `bill_date INTEGER NOT NULL`
3. `pizza_amt INTEGER NOT NULL`

`bill_date` (for the simplicity of the exercise) is the number of days passed since the transaction has been made.

What I'd like to make is the following report:

> ```
> +----------+-----------------+
> | interval | total_pizza_amt |
> +----------+-----------------+
> | 0-29     | X               |
> | 30-59    | Y               |
> | 60+      | Z               |
> +----------+-----------------+
> ```

Basically I'm familiar with the `WITH` keyword but I just realized it isn't supported in MySQL. So I need to generate a *temporary* column somehow and join it with the `PizzaData` table.

How can it be done with MySQL?

Comment: How do you save the number of days passed? Would it change every day? Would you update it daily?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I would write this as:

```
select (case when bill_date < 30 then '0-29'
             when bill_date < 60 then '30-59'
             else '60+'
        end) as bill_range,
       sum(pizza_amt) as total_pizza_amt
from PizzaData
group by bill_range
order by min(bill_date);
```

Notes:

- A `case` expression is guaranteed to evaluate the conditions in order, so you don't need `between`.
- MySQL allows you to use a column alias in the `group by` clause (not all databases do).
- `interval` is a MySQL keyword and a reserved word.  There are better names for the column.
- The `order by` guarantees that the results are in a "logical" order.

Answer (score 2):

I think it's quite easy with `case`:

```
select case when bill_date <= 29 then '0-29'
            when bill_date between 30 and 59 then '30-59'
            else '60+' end `interval`,
       sum(pizza_amt) `total_pizza_amt`
from PizzaData
group by case when bill_date <= 29 then '0-29'
              when bill_date between 30 and 59 then '30-59'
              else '60+' end;
```

or cleaner, using subquery:

```
select `interval`, sum(pizza_amt) `total_pizza_amt` from (
    select case when bill_date <= 29 then '0-29'
                when bill_date between 30 and 59 then '30-59'
                else '60+' end `interval`,
           pizza_amt
    from PizzaData
) `a` group by `interval`;
```